# Export contents as csv in Drupal 8 - Islandora

Tags: csv, export, drupal-8

Have added new repository items and filled all the fields with appropriate details. I wish to export this content as CSV, XML so that changes can be made in the downloaded CSV file and then import this CSV or sync automatically with the uploaded content type. How do I proceed?

**HERE IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Have tried hands-on various modules available online, out of which the VBO export module seemed to be working. But encountered an AJAX 200 error as follows:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=95&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK

#drupal8 #export-csv

Answer (score 0):

Islandora 8 Content is a mix of taxonomy terms, nodes, media and files. Each of which need a migration process and lookup. Checkout [Islandora Workbench](https://github.com/mjordan/islandora_workbench). This is used to "migrate" content in. Migrate is misleading, it's to ingest/create new content. It takes the CSV an imports the content in (media files & taxonomies as well).